# Remote desktop connection to office computer not working?

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop

I have a Windows-7 desktop at office, to which i try to do a remote desktop connection from my home laptop, Windows-Vista home premium. When i say mstsc.exe, enter remote login and password, after some time, it gives an error saying:

Remote Desktop Disconnected: This computer cannot connect to the remote computer. Try contacting system administrator of the remote computer."

On the remote computer:

- I have enabled the services needed for  remote desktop connection, and they are started automatically.
- I have enabled "Allow remote Access to the computer"
- In windows firewall of remote computer, i have allowed Remote Desktop Connection service.

1] How can i fix this and get to do a remote desktop connection to my office computer? Any other settings in need to do on remote computer.

2] FYI - My office has a VPN network setup and i can connect to it. I have tried this remote desktop connection to my office desktop both:- after connecting to the VPN network, and also without connecting to the VPN network. In both cases it was same error and i could not connect.

3] Does VPN have any relation to Remote desktop connections being allowed/disallowed. Do they have relation?

Any pointers would help.

Thank you.

-AD.

Comment: Is the account you are using to connect a member of the local administrators group or in the Remote Desktops Users group on the remote computer? Does your network have a firewall? The RDP port, normally TCP 3389, could be being blocked even if connecting via a VPN.

Comment: Also have you checked from another machine in your office that you are able to connect to the Win 7 desktop via remote desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the account you are using to connect to the remote computer is a member of the local administrators group or in the Remote Desktops Users group on the remote computer.

Answer (score 1):

Can you telnet your PC

telnet PC_IP_ADDRESS 3389

??

Comment: Have Checked all: Account i am using to connect using remote desktop is a member of local administrators group. telnet ip_address 3389 does give error.

Comment: Did you try this when connecting via the VPN? If port 3389 is blocked then there is firewall or other network device blocking the RDP connections to the remote PC from your home.